# How can I find out the POST form sent to an ASP page?

Tags: html, google-chrome, asp-classic

There is an online dictionary I would like to add to my search engine list in Google Chrome. The problem is, the website in question does not show the form used in the address bar, so I can't just substitute the search term with `%s` in Chrome like other search engines.

I know barely anything about developing web pages or web scripting languages, so I'm not even entirely sure that `POST` is the correct term for what is going on here.

[Here](http://www1.euskadi.net/morris/indice_e.htm) is the website I am talking about. If you type a word in the `English-Basque` box and, "dog" for example, and hit `Search`, it just shows `http://www1.euskadi.net/morris/resultado.asp`, obviously not containing "dog". I've inspected the sources of both the HTML page of the first link and the ASP page of the results page, but don't see anything blindingly obvious, but then again I don't really know what I'm looking for.

I use this dictionary a lot, so being able to add it to Chrome and use a simple keyword for it, I can just use the keyword and a search term in the omnibar instead of having to load the page every time, saving much time. :)

If anyone can point me in the right direction for how to figure this out, I would greatly appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: If using GET type parameters don't work, then I'm afraid you're out of luck. You don't have access to the dictionary site, and you can't change the way the search engine list works. Unless you find a way to change the search engine list code so that it can send POST as well as GET parameters. Google Chrome is open source, so it should be possible in theory.

Comment: Well, awhile ago someone made an CHM of one direction of that dictionary, so I assume he had access to it somehow. It's possible that the creator of the CHM was the creator of the site, but I very highly doubt that.

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree So, I found the `form data` section of the Network panel, and found what is being sent, but when I try using the data in the address bar, the website says the page can not be found. For the English->Basque search box, the data is thus: `txtIngles=dog&Submit=Search`. The URL I tried is `http://www1.euskadi.net/morris/resultado.asp?txtIngles=dog&Submit=Search`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Someone else seems to have found a workaround for your problem](https://superuser.com/questions/287658/google-chrome-search-engine-with-search-term-in-post-variable);
It consists of writing a FORM using javascript instead of a URL in Chrome.

A cleaner alternative would be to write a proxy page; a page that you write in asp/php/whatever that can take querystring parameters coming in, and then POST these parameters to the euskadi.net pages, returning the results.

This will require you to have a server or hosted page somewhere online though.

Comment: Well, I was able to get it to work with this site, but like the link you gave says, it won't work from an empty tab. I tried "Awesome New Tab Page" (since Ultimate New Tab seems to not exist anymore) but it says `Refused to execute inline script`. Since I almost always start searches by opening a new tab then using the address bar, loading a page before searching doesn't save any time. I guess I could write a page and host it with lighttpd or something. Thanks for the help though!